# Can someone explain me the concept or intuition of how the depth axis became filter?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In a book I was self-studying about convolutional neural network, the author mentions that

> The convolution operation extracts patches from its input feature
>   map and applies the same transformation to all of these patches, producing an output
>   feature map. This output feature map is still a 3D tensor: it has a width and a height. Its
>   depth can be arbitrary, because the output depth is a parameter of the layer, and the different channels in that depth axis no longer stand for specific colors as in RGB
>   input; rather, they stand for filters."

What I couldn't understand is the part about what happened to the depth parameter in the output feature map? How did it become the filter? As far as I know, filters are matrices applied to detect edges, shapes etc.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the first layer of a convolutional network, which takes as input and RGB (so 3 channels) image, and that outputs `K` featuremaps (that is, a tensor of size `batch_size, K, width, height`). Each single channel among those `K` channels is produced by its own convolution filter. That is, channel `i` is produced by a filter with weights and bias `W_i, b_i`. As a result, sometimes in the litterature, you might see that language abuse: instead of saying the `i-th` channel from the output, some authors will just say the `i-th` filter.

Comment: So filters and channels are interchange able words used .Thanks.